# React: prevent child components from being rendering until data is fetched

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a wrapper component to either show a loading spinner, error message or the child components depending on if data has been fetched in React.
However, even while the page is loading (`this.state.loading === true`) meaning the child content should not be rendered, React is still either rendering or processing the child components in some way and will throw the error `Cannot read property 'useRoundedImages' of undefined`.

```js
// page.js
export default class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            error: undefined,
            user: undefined,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        getData(...).then(res => {
            this.setState({ loading: false, user: res.data.user});
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <LoadWrapper loading={this.state.loading} error={this.state.error}>
                <p>{this.state.user.options.useRoundedImages}</p>
            </LoadWrapper>
            );
        }
    }
}

// loading-wrapper.js
export default class LoadWrapper extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.loading ? <Spinner animation="border" className="mx-auto d-block" /> :
                this.props.error ? <ErrorPage error={this.props.error}></ErrorPage> :
                    <>{this.props.children}</>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I prevent these elements from being rendered, or is there a better way I should be conditionally rendering my loading spinner, error message and child components?

Comment: `useRoundedImages ` is used where?

Comment: Inside the child components of `LoadWrapper`. It is just being displayed as a test.

Comment: Can you put this on `codesandbox` minimal example. Its easy to debug there?http://react.new/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue come here:

```
<LoadWrapper loading={this.state.loading} error={this.state.error}>
        <p>{this.state.user?.options.useRoundedImages}</p>
</LoadWrapper>
```

The issue here is that inside `Page` component it go each and every line. Your `LoadWrapper` logic is correct. But when you `Page` component renders it goes in each line so it means your `LoadWrapper` will does not generate child component but your `Page` component goes in each line that's why its giving this error as at that time there is no `user` value present. `Cannot read property 'useRoundedImages' of undefined`. You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent this

Here I replicate your logic and created POC. Hope you got the context:
Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class LoadWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return <>Loading...</>;
    } else if (this.props.error) {
      return <>Error....</>;
    } else {
      return <>{this.props.children}</>;
    }
  }
}

class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      error: undefined,
      user: undefined
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        user: {
          options: {
            useRoundedImages: "test"
          }
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LoadWrapper loading={this.state.loading} error={this.state.error}>
        <p>{this.state.user?.options.useRoundedImages}</p>
      </LoadWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Page />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-water-mgwp2?file=/src/App.js:0-1078